# Make change in media library affect images in published articles

Tags: plugins, images, media-library

Is there any way/plugin to make wordpress change the description/alt text/caption of an image used in already written articles if I change any of those texts of that specific image in the media library?

Comment: As far as I know, nope. If it puts it inline you basically have to manually edit it. Which is dumb.